# ClamAV finds infected files in ClamAV setup directory!

Tags: clamav

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6565044
Engine version: 0.101.4
Scanned directories: 41221
Scanned files: 287903
Infected files: 49
Total errors: 6
Data scanned: 8857.80 MB
Data read: 7429.20 MB (ratio 1.19:1)
Time: 2788.016 sec (46 m 28 s)
```

[image: screenshot of ClamAV log]

I am unable to understand how this is possible. Is it detecting it's own virus definition files as infected files? I have since deleted the directory. Also clamscan takes up about 780-820 MB of RAM at 13-22% CPU usage on average. Is this normal?

Comment: So? Only suggestion I can offer: delete it. ClamAV uses --windows-- rules to scan linux files. After thorough analysis at my company: virusscanners are useless for Linux. Rootkit detectors are what you want to check for. We don't get virusses unless we install them ourself (as of today that is ;-)) Stick to known sources for installations and we can all live without a virusscanner.

Comment: Those are test files anyway for the scanner to make sure that it is working.  Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Rinzwind Well that's true, but I have to use software from untrusted sources sometimes because of my work requirements. What rootkit detectors would you recommend?